# I want to install picamera but I get this error:

Tags: python

When I try to run "pip install --user picamera" this command on cmd OS(window).

It throws the following error. anyone here help me?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's not meant for windows - just linux (or possibly mac)

Comment: can you tell me solution for window?

Comment: Picamera is a library to use together with the Raspberry Pi camera. It doesn't work on Windows and there is no reason too work there since the picamera only runs on linux.